# Convert MutableList<Any> to MutableList<Object>

Tags: kotlin, mapper

Actually I have this data class where data is a mutableList ,

```
data class DataTable (
    var total: Long = 0,

    @JsonProperty("data")
    var data: MutableList<Any>? = null )
```

my idea is that when that data arrives I can map it to a very important entity as I could do and tried to do this

```
 val summaryOrder2= dataTable.data as  MutableList<SummaryOrder>
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the issue with casting the list?

Another way you might be able to achieve this is to filter the instance

```
val summaryOrder2 = dataTable.data?.filterIsInstance<SummaryOrder>()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are showing is a cast... what you probably want is either a [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) or [`filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html).

**Why is casting here a bad idea?** Because generic type information is erased at runtime... you can even do `mutableListOf<Apple>() as List<Orange>` and will probably be shocked at runtime ;-) (note: such casts are therefore also mentioned as "unchecked casts")

**Why [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) or [`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html)?** Use [`map`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html) if you need to transform the contents of the `data`-list to those objects... Use [`filter`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter.html) (or [`filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html)) to filter out all those entries that match your criteria/predicate.

You may want to look up the referenced documentation.

So the possible solutions demonstrated:

```
data?.filterIsInstance<SummaryOrder>()

data?.filterIsInstance<SomeTransformable>()
    ?.map { it.toSummaryOrder() /* or whatever makes those instances a SummaryOrder */ }
```

Some more recommendations:

- try to omit nullable list types (doesn't it suffice to have an empty or non-empty list?)
- try to omit `Any` as list type; otherwise you need to use [`filterIsInstance`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/filter-is-instance.html) for anything you do with it